# BeautifulSoup only identifying 2 of 5 tables

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm working on my first python project and hit a snag. I'm trying to use BeautifulSoup to scrape data from some tables on this site: https://www.basketball-reference.com/awards/awards_2020.html

When I use the following code, I am able to get data from the first two tables but the other three aren't recognized (i.e. len(tables) =2 when it should =5)

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.basketball-reference.com/awards/awards_{}.html'.format(awardyear)
page = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

tables = soup.find_all('table')
len(tables)
```

When I print soup, all the tables are in the html so I'm not sure why the last three aren't recognized. I've spent some time trying to spot a difference between the tables that are/aren't being recognized, but have come up empty so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is happening because the other 3 tables are within HTML comments `<!-- .... -->`.

You can extract the tables checking if the tags are of the type [`Comment`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#comments-and-other-special-strings):

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, Comment


URL = "https://www.basketball-reference.com/awards/awards_2020.html"

soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(URL).content, "html.parser")

# Find all comments
comments = soup.find_all(text=lambda t: isinstance(t, Comment))
comment_soup = BeautifulSoup(str(comments), "html.parser")

print("The length of tables:", len(soup.find_all("table")))

print("The length of tables within comments:", len(comment_soup.find(class_="table_outer_container")))
```

Output:

```
The length of tables: 2
The length of tables within comments: 3
```

Comment: Thanks for your help!